# Using for loops to lock out a user in Arduino

Tags: arduino, timeout

I'm having trouble with my code for a digital code lock project. I managed to get most of it working, but there is one section which is confusing me. There is a set of 6 switches, 2 buttons, a green LED and red LED. The switches can be turned on or off in any order. Once the order is set using the 1st button (using pin 8), it is stored as a series of 6 variables. This part works fine.

The next part is the one which checks to see if each variable is equal to its corresponding switch, when the 2nd button (pin 12) is pressed. If all of them are, then the green LED lights up. Otherwise, the user gets 2 more tries. If the user enters the wrong series of switches 3 times, then they are locked out for 10 seconds. This is where I'm having trouble using a for loop properly. I'm using Tinkercad's block coding system, and I don't know how to close the loop. Here is the entire code so far:

```
int switch0 = 0;

int switch1 = 0;

int switch2 = 0;

int switch3 = 0;

int switch4 = 0;

int switch5 = 0;

int switchChecker = 0;

int i = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(A5, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(A4, INPUT);
  pinMode(A3, INPUT);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(12, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // this records the values of all 6 switches on 1st
  // button press
  if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH) {
    switch0 = digitalRead(A5);
    Serial.println(switch0);
    switch1 = digitalRead(A4);
    Serial.println(switch1);
    switch2 = digitalRead(A3);
    Serial.println(switch2);
    switch3 = digitalRead(A2);
    Serial.println(switch3);
    switch4 = digitalRead(A1);
    Serial.println(switch4);
    switch5 = digitalRead(A0);
    Serial.println(switch5);
  }
  // when the 2nd button is pressed, a for loop is
  // started to check if the switches are the same
  // order
  if (digitalRead(12) == HIGH) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i += 1) {
      if (digitalRead(A5) == switch0 && (digitalRead(A4) == switch1 && (digitalRead(A3) == switch2 && (digitalRead(A2) == switch3 && (digitalRead(A1) == switch4 && digitalRead(A0) == switch5))))) {
        i = 3;
      }
    }
  }
  // if the conditions are met, the for loop closes
  // and the green LED turns on
  if (i == 3) {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  } else {
    delay(10000); // Wait for 10000 millisecond(s)
  }
}
```

Finally, if I wanted to make the user get locked out after 3 incorrect tries *after* the initial lockout, and set that delay to a certain amount of time, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a for loop, you can create a global variable that counts the number of wrong attempts. Then, if it is equal to 3, you call the delay:

```
char wrongAttemps = 0;

void loop()
{
    // this records the values of all 6 switches on 1st
    // button press
    if (digitalRead(8) == HIGH) {
        switch0 = digitalRead(A5);
        Serial.println(switch0);
        switch1 = digitalRead(A4);
        Serial.println(switch1);
        switch2 = digitalRead(A3);
        Serial.println(switch2);
        switch3 = digitalRead(A2);
        Serial.println(switch3);
        switch4 = digitalRead(A1);
        Serial.println(switch4);
        switch5 = digitalRead(A0);
        Serial.println(switch5);
    }

    // when the 2nd button is pressed,
    // check if the switches are the same order
    if (digitalRead(12) == HIGH) {
        if (digitalRead(A5) == switch0 && digitalRead(A4) == switch1
            && digitalRead(A3) == switch2 && digitalRead(A2) == switch3
            && (digitalRead(A1) == switch4 && digitalRead(A0) == switch5
        ) {
            // right combination
            digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        } else {
            // wrong combination
            digitalWrite(2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

            wrongAttemps++;

            if (wrongAttemps == 3) {
                delay(10000);
                wrongAttemps = 0;   // reset attemps
            }
        }
    }
}
```